# How to parse date using 'dd-MMM-yyyy' with @JsonFormat in Java?

Tags: java, json, date, jackson

how can I parse date to 'dd-MMM-yyyy' format using @JsonFormat from Jackson library? I am using Java 8 and Jackson 2.8.9.

Example:
I would like to get: 2019-06-22T00:00:00Z -> 22-Jun-2019

I am using

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyy")
private Date myDate;
```

and I receive an exception:

> JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2019-06-22T00:00:Z": expected format "dd-MMM-yyyy"

I thought I would be able to parse that date to expected format, but it looks like it is impossible in that way. Do you have any suggestions how can I do it? Im looking for the best approach. Can I do it using this annotation?

Comment: are you on java 8+ version?

Comment: You have one format in your question, another in your code sample and none of them match the input String. 
If you have the date in a String to start with you must parse the incoming String first. Once you have it represented in an object you can format the output the way you want. But I am not sure that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Govi S: I am on Java 8

Comment: @DanielBarbarian: Sorry. It was a mistake in my code, now it's good format. This myDate variable is part of a model, I am looking for a way to do an instant parsing without additional methods or objects.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats to use when exchanging date-time values as text.

Answer (score 1):

As you are on java 8, you should use `LocalDate` and not the old API.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
private final LocalDate localDate;
```

I was able to de-serialize with `Date` API also. If it doesn't work, try updating jackson artifact.

Comment: I did it the same like you did, but I've got an exception: 
_java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-22T00:00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 2_ - I added dependency _jackson-datatype-jsr310_ and created ObjectMapper Bean with JavaTimeModule().

Comment: Try updating Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

use this library dateFormat

```
 dateFormat('your date variable', "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

always does the trick